# How to make this geometrical "translation" effect with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, geometry

I'm trying to do an effect that i've seen on a website.
You can have a look at this [site](http://www.ultranoir.com/fr/#!/blog/accueil/) :
http://www.ultranoir.com/fr/#!/blog/accueil/

Or you can see this screenshot :

[image: screenshot translation effect]

If you over a div, you will see a sort of 3D effect. First, i don't know how to call this effect. It's a kind of [Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29).

Maybe there is a better name ?

I would like to do something like that.

I've analyzed the source code and i saw that the website is using a background image :

http://www.ultranoir.com/cdn/gene/image/common/blog/grid_item_m.gif

You can see the picture :

[image]

So, here is what i've done but it's not perfect.
You can see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/ARgxU/).
Feel free to edit the fiddle.

Can you help to do better ?

I think i don't need to use a background image, it could be done with only css
http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/BrzuV/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document sans nom</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var $bt_bienvenue = $("#bt_bienvenue");
var $bt_bienvenue2 = $("#bt_bienvenue2");

$bt_bienvenue.hover(
         function () {
           $bt_bienvenue.transition({ x: '-10px', y: '-10px' });
           $bt_bienvenue2.fadeIn(1000);
         }, 
         function () {
           $bt_bienvenue.transition({ x: '0px', y: '0px' });
           $bt_bienvenue2.fadeOut(100);
         }
     );
});
</script>
<style>
#test {
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#000;
}

#container {
    padding:30px;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#bt_bienvenue {
    background-color:#e5322c;
    width:95px;
    height:190px;
    z-index:3;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    /*display:none;*/
}

#bt_bienvenue2 { 
    background:url(img/site/bgd-bienvenue.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
    /*float:left;*/
    width:105px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    top:-10px;
    left:-10px;
    z-index:2;
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--<div id="test"></div>-->
<div id="container">
    <div id="bt_bienvenue">Menu</div>
    <div id="bt_bienvenue2"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd of thought this was achieved with `CSS` using multiple `box-shadow`'s

Comment: @Novocaine88 I think i don't need a background image, only css for the background : http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/BrzuV/

Comment: Here's an example of what i mean: http://jsfiddle.net/sgmg7/1/

Comment: @Novocaine88 really nice css code, only box-shadow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way :

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $bt_bienvenue = $("#bt_bienvenue");
var $bt_container = $("#container");

$bt_bienvenue.hover(
         function () {
           $bt_container.transition({ x: '-5px', y: '-5px', width: '105px', height: '205px' },200);

         }, 
         function () {
             $bt_container.transition({ x: '0px', y: '0px', width: '100px', height: '200px' },200);

         }
     );
});
```

You add `overflow:hidden;` to your container, that has exactly the same width/height as your `Menu`. And transition will only affect your container. You scale it (105px*205px) and slide it to the top-left 5px each.

And the more you scale and slide it, the more steps you have to add in the box-shadow property.

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/ARgxU/14/

Comment: Really smart solution. The #container is a mask.